# Problem debugging C++ code from .NET application

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, debugging

I have .NET service (C#) that uses a couple of c++ libraries. I have a desperate need to get into C++ methods but when I set the breakpoints they get disabled in the run time.

Where to look at?

I set "Attach Debugger" in C++ project settings but this does not seem to change a bit.

Please advice. Where to look at?

The libraries are [quickfix engine](http://www.quickfixengine.org) if anyone cares.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to [enable unmanaged code debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdw0c6sf.aspx) for your project. To do this:

1. Right-click on your project in the Solution Explorer, and click "Properties".
2. In the "Debug" tab, check the box labeled "Enable unmanaged code debugging".

[image]

By default, a project targeting the .NET Framework will only debug managed code. You have to tell it explicitly that you want to debug unmanaged code.

If that doesn't fix the problem, also make sure that the "Enable Just My Code" setting is not turned on in the debug settings found in the Options dialog.

---

> Does not work when i attach to process. Only works when i run from the studio

Correct. When you attach to a process, your project isn't [necessarily] loaded, and Visual Studio doesn't pay any attention to its settings.

In this situation, you need to set the appropriate options in the "Attach to Process" dialog. To do so:

1. Click the "Select..." button at the end of the line labeled "Attach to:".
2. In the dialog that appears, make sure that "Native" is checked, in addition to the appropriate version of "Managed" code.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean main application project (where Main() is located)?

Comment: @Captain: I'm not really sure what you're asking. You need to enable this for your **startup** project. I assume that's the .NET app.

Comment: Does not work when i attach to process. Only works when i run from the studio

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Project Properties` -> `Debug` -> and set the checkbox

`Enable unmanaged code debugging`

HTH